# I just changed my Minecraft name and now I can't join a server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just changed my Minecraft gamertag and it was all ok, then when I try to join a server it says this "Failed to join server Error: Authentication to Minecraft.net Failed"

Comment: Log out of the game and the launcher, then log in again and all should be good.

Comment: Hey @GiantTree, please post answers as answers and not as comments, this time, someone did it for you, but do it yourself next time, so you can take the reputation etc

Answer (score 4):

Simply re-login to the Minecraft launcher. If this does not work, you may need to update the launcher [here](http://minecraft.net/download).